# `git-branch` keeps showing remote `upstream/master` after removing it

Tags: git

I decided to remove the *upstream* remote reference from my local repository, but `git-branch` keeps showing `remotes/upstream/master`. I *pruned* the references, but it keeps showing *upstream*. **How do I clean it properly?**

---

Here is what I had, what I did, and what I have:

> Fetching from `upstream` was broken, that's why I decided to remove *upstream*
> (since I'm not using it anyways):
>
> ```bash
> git fetch --all
> Fetching origin
> remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
> remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
> remote: Total 9 (delta 4), reused 8 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
> Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), done.
> From github.com:dockerstuff/docker-jupyterhub-deploy
>    a977d21..7393fc7  master     -> origin/master
> Fetching upstream
> fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master
> error: Could not fetch upstream
> ```

```bash
$ git remote -v 
origin  git@github.com:dockerstuff/docker-jupyterhub-deploy (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:dockerstuff/docker-jupyterhub-deploy (push)
upstream    https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker.git (push)
```

```bash
$ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/master
```

```bash
$ git remote remove upstream
```

```bash
$ git branch -a 
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/master
```

```bash
$ git fetch -p --all
Fetching origin
```

```bash
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/master
```

```bash
git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:dockerstuff/docker-jupyterhub-deploy (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:dockerstuff/docker-jupyterhub-deploy (push)
```

```bash
$ git remote prune upstream
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

```bash
$ git remote prune origin
```

```bash
git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/master
```

> *Why is `remote/upstram/master` still there?*

Comment: The title says `origin` but your question uses `upstream`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+remote-tracking+branch

Comment: `git branch -r -d upstram/master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `git branch -a` command lists both local and remote branches.

The `remotes/upstream/master` branch you see is a remote tracking branch that is stored locally to keep track of the state of the upstream repository.

Try this once :

```
git branch -d -r upstream/master
```

After that if you run `git branch -a` again, you can check if the `remotes/upstream/master` branch is no longer listed.

Please let me know if you still issues.